# jQuery: xml: How to change xml code via jQuery and id

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, odoo

I'm trying to change content in an XML by using jQuery.
From the examples that I've been looking up I think the code should be something like this:

**javascript:**

```
get_verrichtingen: function(){
    var self = this;
    var optie = "hello";

    self.$( "#verrichting-select" ).html( '<option value="' + optie + '">' + optie + '</option>' );
},
```

XML:

```
<div id="cashier-frame">
    <t t-esc="widget.get_verrichtingen()">
        <select>id="verrichting-select"</select>
    </t>
</div>
```

My goal is to create a dropdown menu later.
I think the reason this doesn't work might have to do something with where I've put the id="verrichting-select".

But I THINK it should be there because `<select><option value="Hallo">Hallo</option></select>` actually works?

Right now with the jQuery, the dropdown is just empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

**edit:** FYI: I'm trying to do this in Odoo Point of Sale.

**edit for Emipro Technologies Pvt:**
I can only see "All" in the dropdown but can't click it to see other values.
I've tried to make a very simple dropdown, but this doesn't work either. I only see "Volvo" with the code below:

```
<div id="cashier-frame">
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
```

[image]

I can't click the arrow.
Could this have something to do with Odoo?

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about XML? Or did you mean HTML? If you don't have a framework or something there won't be a 'dropdown'. Please consider reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML If you did mean HTML please change your tags

Comment: I am sure it is XML. I'm not sure if you're familiar with it but this is a piece of code I'm trying to put into the Point Of Sale webapp in Odoo.
What do you mean about the framework and there won't be a dropdown?

Comment: Than please add the name of this webapp or the framework this uses :) I wondered why you would try to make some visual effects out of a XML and some js. This webapp seems to interpretate XML. Because otherwise you wouldn't see anything :)

Comment: btw, I also see a little white box with an arrow pointing down. So I guess there will be a dropdown?

Comment: Because the options of the dropdown menu should be variable depending on the Odoo database. Later on I'll get a list of the options via javascript. This is just to test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in few steps,

First you need to define dropdown in xml,

```
<select id="sele_filter" name="sele_filter">
    <option value="All" selected="true">All</option>
</select>
```

Then in your widget code you need to build options first and then append it to the dropdown.

```
var options = "";
var i=0;
options += '<option value="' + i++ + '">' + i + </option>';
options += '<option value="' + i++ + '">' + i + </option>';
options += '<option value="' + i++ + '">' + i + </option>';

this.$el.find('#sele_filter').append(options);
```

**$el** will accessible through out Point of Sale.

Comment: I've tried it but didn't work. But I think there might be something else wrong? See my edit in the OP.